# Template class on a abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class

So I have a class template `Foo`:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
   //...
};
```

I have two derived classes from the Foo class:

```
class FooDerived1 : public Foo<int>
{
public:
    FooDerived1 ();
    ~FooDerived1 ();
};

class FooDerived2 : public Foo<double>
{
public:
    FooDerived2 ();
    ~FooDerived2 ();
};
```

But now I saw that the class template was being used on a abstract class `IBar` like this:

```
class Foo;

class IBar
{
public:
    virtual void placeFoo(Foo& foo) = 0; //error
    virtual void removeFoo(Foo& foo) = 0;
};
```

**I know I cannot use templates classes in abstract virtual classes.**

**But..in a case like this, what should I do?**

I really need the IBar abstract class like this...

**Forget the usage of template classes?**

Comment: You may try static polymorphism, also known as [CRTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: A template instance **can** be used as an abstract base class. But the instances are not interchangeable. So you either need a common abstract base for all `Foo<>`'s or rethink your design.

Comment: You seem to have defined `Foo<T>` but forward declared and used `class Foo`.  Those can't go together.  I assume that (rather than anything about `virtual`) is your real problem.  But without quoted error messages or a better example, you aren't giving much hint at the real problem.

Comment: No such thing as abstract virtual class. Do you mean "abstract classes" or "virtual functions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Make `IBar` itself a template class.

```
template <class T>
class Foo;

template <class T>
class IBar
{
public:
    virtual void placeFoo(Foo<T>& foo) = 0;
    virtual void removeFoo(Foo<T>& foo) = 0;
};
```

Option 2: Make all `Foo<T>` derive from a common, non-generic `FooBase`.

```
class FooBase
{
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
class Foo : public FooBase
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    //...
};

// ...

class FooBase;

class IBar
{
public:
    virtual void placeFoo(FooBase& foo) = 0;
    virtual void removeFoo(FooBase& foo) = 0;
};
```

The viability of both solutions depends on how much you actually depend on the `T` type. But that's what you should expect when you mix virtual functions with templates. With option 1, you do not have a common interface type anymore; with option 2, `FooBase` cannot provide any member function with a `T`-dependent argument.

---

By the way, don't forget about virtual destructors in your real code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need common behaviour, create base class for all instances of `Foo<>`:

```
class FooBase
{
    //common interface and data
};

template <class T>
class Foo : public FooBase
{
};
```

And then:

```
class FooBase;

class IBar
{
public:
    virtual void placeFoo(FooBase& foo) = 0; //ok
    virtual void removeFoo(FooBase& foo) = 0;
};
```

The thing is, that you try to mix templates (compile time) and dynamic polymorphism (runtime), which can be problematic (is it what you meant by *"I know I cannot use templates classes in abstract virtual classes"*?).

Why not stick to using templates?

```
class IBar
{
public:
    template <class T>
    void placeFoo(Foo<T>& foo);

    template <class T>
    void removeFoo(Foo<T>& foo);
};
```

or:

```
template <class T>
class IBar
{
public:
    void placeFoo(Foo<T>& foo);
    void removeFoo(Foo<T>& foo);
};
```